# Unity | MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: unity-game-engine

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

```
UnityEngine.Transform.get_position () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/EditorGenerated/UnityEngineTransform.cs:28)

Destroy+$SpawnAfter5Seconds$1+$.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Destroy.js:22)
```

Any help?

Comment: You're destroying the object reference , rather than the instantiated one. Instantiate a variable to hold the object and destroy that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tying to perform an operation on an object which is now `null` because it was `Destroyed`.

Solution

Don't Destroy it or don't try to access something that is already destroyed. You can always check like this:

```
if(transformReference != null)
{
    // Safe to use. 
}
```

Comment: But I didn't destroy it

Answer (score 0):

It means that the object you are trying to move, change position, etc. id destroyed.
Try making a new object called like the object you used in your script. If it doesn't help, post the script in a comment.
Have a great day!